# Changing values in other parts of a class Unreal C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Basically, I want to increment the Z-axis everytick of an object. I can do this no problem in Blueprint but I can't seem to figure out how to access the begin play part of the class from the tick and increment ActorLocation.

```
    // Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#include "MoveUp.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"


// Sets default values for this component's properties
UMoveUp::UMoveUp()
{
    // Set this component to be initialized when the game starts, and to be ticked every frame.  You can turn these features
    // off to improve performance if you don't need them.
    PrimaryComponentTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    // ...
}


// Called when the game starts
void UMoveUp::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    AActor* Owner = GetOwner();
    FVector ActorLocation = FVector(0.f,0.f,200.f);
    Owner->SetActorLocation(ActorLocation, false) ;
}


// Called every frame
void UMoveUp::TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction)
{
    Super::TickComponent(DeltaTime, TickType, ThisTickFunction);

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `UMoveUp:BeginPlay()`, you can set initial values. It is called only once, when actor is spawned. You want to use `TickComponent`:

```
// Called every frame
void UMoveUp::TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction)
{
    Super::TickComponent(DeltaTime, TickType, ThisTickFunction);

    // this could be "cached" as private property - better performance
    auto owner = GetOwner();  

    // now we need to actually move by Delta * base value
    // note that we are ignoring actor's rotation
    auto newActorLocation = owner->GetActorLocation() + FVector(0.f,0.f,200.f) * DeltaTime;  

    owner->SetActorLocation(newActorLocation, false);
}
```

It is important to use `DeltaTime`, because your *FPS* value can (and would) change over time and also it depends on game (visual) settings and user's PC. Using `DeltaTime` ensure same experience regardless on framerate.

Another possible approach is by using `UPrimitiveComponent::AddForce(...)` ([UE Docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/UPrimitiveComponent/AddForce/index.html)). This is more physics-based approach and it is good for a more complex simulations.